# How do you make these buttons?

Tags: android, button

I am trying to make buttons of a similar nature to the buttons seen in the google+ app. Do you just declare these in XML like a regular button and just apply a custom style? Does anyone know generally what these buttons are and a sort of method for how to generate a look like this?

[image]

Comment: Theyre images with registered command listeners.

Comment: as @Steven said, technically, it can be anything which has a click event and a background property set to an image/drawable(xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be anything that registered with a `OnClickListener`, something like: `ImageButton`, `ImageView`, a `Layout` w/ background image...

However, in my opinion, ImageButton is the best w/ some pre-defined functions for button-like effects/shapes.

Answer (score 0):

an example can be found here http://code.google.com/p/iosched/